# Is there a way to "remove" the parts of a functor that do not store its argument?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, functor, type-constructor

Given a functor (or any type constructor) `f`, we can get a "version" of that functor that does not contain a value of its argument. We just define `newtype NoArg f = NoArg (f Void)`. For example:

- `NoArg []` is just the empty list.
- `NoArg Maybe` is just Nothing.
- `NoArg (Either e)` is just `e`.
- `NoArg (Identity)` is `Void`.
- `NoArg IO` is an IO action that produces effects forever (like a server).
- `Functor f => NoArg (Free f)` is `Fix f`.
- etc...

My question is if we can do the opposite, and create a type of the constructors of a Functor that *does* use its argument. Formally, `Arg :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *)` should be such that there is a term `forall a. Arg f a -> a` or equivalently `Arg f Void -> Void`. For example:

- `Arg [] a` is the type of non empty lists of type `a`.
- `Arg Maybe a` is just `a`.
- `Arg (Either e) a` is just `a`.
- `Arg Identity a` is just `a`.
- `Arg IO a` *you would think* is IO actions that produce a result. This probably will not be the case though since you there is no function from `IO a` to `a`, or even `Maybe a` that isn't `const Nothing`.
- `Functor f => Arg (Free f) a` is `Free (Arg f) a`.
- etc...

I'm thinking `Arg f` would be some sort of "supremum" of the functors `g` that embed in `f` such that there exists a term `Argful g :: g Void -> Void`.

EDIT: I guess the true test would be for `Arg [] a` to be isomorphic to `NomEmpty a`, where

```
data NonEmpty a = One a | Cons a (NonEmpty a)
```

Comment: I think the closest we can get is `Arg f a = (a, f a)`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're after, or even what your `NoArg` does. In particular, it appears that it must be a type, I guess of kind `(* -> *) -> *` (certainly this is what your `Either e` example does - but in all the other examples it seems to result in a *value* rather than a *type*. (In which case `NoArg` would not be a type at all, but a polymorphic constant, of type `(SomeClass a) => a` where `SomeClass` is whatever class you define which include this `NoArg` method. Please correct me if I'm wrong though, my Haskell knowledge is almost certainly less than yours!

Comment: I don't think you can force a functor to use its argument.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I was a little sloppy with how I wrote it. `NoArg` is in fact `(* -> *) -> *`. When I said `NoArg []` is the empty list, I meant that is a type whose only value if the empty list. When I said `NoArg (Either e)` is `e`, I meant it is a type isomorphic to `e`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt there's a solution in Haskell, but there's a fairly simple definition in languages with dependent pairs and equality types. I work in Idris below.

First, we say that two elements in an `f` functor have the same shape if they become equal after being filled with `()`:

```
SameShape : Functor f => f a -> f b -> Type
SameShape fa fb = (map (const ()) fa = map (const ()) fb)
```

The elements of `Arg f a` are elements of `f a` such that there are no elements of `f Void` with the same shape.

```
Arg : (f : Type -> Type) -> Functor f => Type -> Type
Arg f a = (fa : f a ** ((fv : f Void) -> SameShape fa fv -> Void))
```

`**` denotes a dependent pair where the component on the right may refer to the first component. This definition excludes exactly those values which don't contain `a`. So, we have the desired property:

```
lem : Functor f => Arg f Void -> Void
lem (fv ** p) = p fv Refl
```

where `Refl` proves `map (const ()) fv = map (const ()) fv`.

This doesn't work for `IO`, but I don't expect there's any sensible definition for that.

Comment: I think a big question is whether the OP is satisfied with `Arg f Void -> Void` or if they want the much stronger `forall a. Arg f a -> a`.

Comment: @dfeuer I thought they were the same. I guess they're not. I would prefer the second.

Comment: @dfeuer I realized that if you only require the first, then the Haskell type `exists g. (g Void -> Void, forall a. g a -> f a, g a)` would work. Unfortunately changing `g Void -> Void` to `forall a. g a -> a` results in extraneous information. (For example, for a list, it would not only prove that `Arg f a` uses its element, but also pick one.)

Comment: @PyRulez, the question is whether you want to be able to pick one, yes. It's a typical constructive logic matter: the first statement basically says that it doesn't fail to contain its argument; the second says that it contains it. For practical programming, a proof of a double negative isn't usually all that useful; you just can't do much with it.

Comment: @dfeuer I added an edit to the question that might clarify my question.

Comment: @PyRulez I don’t see what you think is good about either `exists g. (g Void -> Void, forall a. g a -> f a, g a)` or `exists g. (forall a. g a -> a, forall a. g a -> f a, g a)`. Given [`data Proxy t = Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html#t:Proxy), surely you’d like `Arg Proxy ()` to be uninhabited, but under both these implementations of `Arg`, it would be inhabited by `(runIdentity, const Proxy, Identity ())`.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg oh whoops, NVM.

Comment: @PyRulez My solution passes the test mentioned in your edited question.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Yeah, but it technically isn't haskell. Still interesting though!